# How to check if form is filled up in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form and a submit button and a modal. I want to run the modal to show a message if the form has an empty value.

I tried .each to loop and check the form for empty inputs but even when the form is filled up it still returns as empty.

My html form:

```
  <form id="register_form" role="form" >
    <label >First Name</label>
    <input id="inN"data-error="Enter first name." required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input id="inL"  data-error="Enter last name." required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
          <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" data-error="Enter email." required>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my javascript:

```
$('#register_form').each(function() {
            if ( $(this).val() === '' ){
                console.log($(this).val()); // empty even when form is not
                vm.message = 'One or Two fields are empty. Please fill up all fields'
                document.getElementById("message").textContent=vm.message; // message on the modal
            };


        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `$('#register_form input').each` instead of `$('#register_form').each` to loop through all the `input` fields present in form.

**Please note** that, if you have `select` box or `textarea` fields in your real `form` then this code needs to be modified accordingly. I will also suggest you to look at [JQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin which do all these work for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#submitButton").click(function() {
    ValidateForm();
  });

});

function ValidateForm() {

  var formInvalid = false;
  $('#register_form input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
      formInvalid = true;
    }
  });

  if (formInvalid)
    alert('One or Two fields are empty. Please fill up all fields');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="register_form" role="form">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input id="inN" data-error="Enter first name." required>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input id="inL" data-error="Enter last name." required>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" data-error="Enter email." required>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I had to add $('#register_form input, select').each(function() for drop down list.

Comment: but why doest it update and functions still sees it as empty even when user adds value into input tags after the first checking....?

Comment: it should not happen like that. Assume that first time you directly clicks on submit button; then obviously all the fields are empty and hence you will get alert. Now before clicking on submit button again, fill all 3 fields and then click button. This time you will not get alert as all 3 fields are already been filled.

Comment: yea, thats the logic, but it seems to not do so. Im not sure what the problem is because i console log all the inputs and there are values in, but when run the fuction again it reads it as null...

Answer (score 1):

try below code

replace jquery selector with below code

`$('#register_form input')`

you can simply fix  it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var allInput = $('input');

    $.each(allInput,function(){
     //looping through all input assuming u have one form in the page  u can pass form id and grab input too
    if($(this).val() == ""){
    alert('empty');
//do something append error msgs etc
    } else {
    alert('you can go');
    }

    });
```

Comment: This will select ALL inputs on the page …

Comment: yes you want to select all input and check if empty or not ? or give id to form and check $("#formId input"); this will select all input from form id ="formId"

Answer (score 0):

It always show you blank value in text box, because when your JavaScript code execute that time all text box reset, check below image for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#signupForm')
    .formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        err: {
            container: '#errors'
        },
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            firstName: {
                row: '.col-xs-4',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The first name is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            lastName: {
                row: '.col-xs-4',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The last name is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            username: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The username must be more than 5 and less than 31 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The email address is required'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'The email address is not valid'
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required'
                    },
                    different: {
                        field: 'username',
                        message: 'The password cannot be the same as username'
                    }
                }
            },
            gender: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The gender is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            bio: {
                validators: {
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 300,
                        message: 'The bio must be less than 300 characters long'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .on('err.form.fv', function(e) {
        // Show the message modal
        $('#messageModal').modal('show');
    });
  });
 </script>
```

[**Demo**](http://formvalidation.io/examples/showing-messages-modal/)